# Deciphering the meaning of the `sgr` variable in `tput`

Tags: terminal, tput

Does anybody know what `sgr` stands for when using tput?  It is supposed to reset the colour scheme to its default colour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sgr` is short for "[Select Graphic Rendition](https://terminalguide.namepad.de/seq/csi_sm/)", which is also known as "Set Attribute" (see the `terminfo(5)` manual; `man 5 terminfo`).

What you are most likely using is `sgr0` though, which resets all set attributes.

Comment: Correct.  Am using `sgr0`. Thanks.

Comment: @waltinator Could you say something more about that? There is no manual on a default Ubuntu Focal system for `control_codes`, and there is no mentioning of that string in the `tput(1)` manual.  I also saw you making this comment [elsewhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/659694/colouring-arguments-based-on-a-numeric-value#comment1242284_659694), and it was as confusing there as here.

Comment: My bad. It's actually `man console_codes`.