# Colouring arguments based on a numeric value

Tags: bash, colors

I have a number of string arguments passed to a bash function, each one to be printed on a separate line.

Would like to modify the code in such a way that the numeric value of `warn` is the number of lines printed in red, starting from the first argument in `${@}`.

```
rge='^[0-9]+$'
if [[ -v warn && "$warn" == "1" ]]; then
  printf '%s\n' ${red}"$1"${sgr}  # first line red
  printf '%s\n' "${@:2}"          # remaining, uncoloured
elif [[ -v warn && "$warn" =~ $rge ]]; then
  printf '%s\n' ${red}"$@"${sgr}  # all lines red
fi
```

As first attempts I have

```
elif [[ -v warn && "$warn" =~ $rge ]]; then
  argc=$#
  argv=("$@")
  printf "%s\n" "argc: $argc"
  for (( j=0; j<warn; j++ )); do
    printf '%s\n' ${red}"${argv[j]}"${sgr}
  done

  #printf '%s\n' ${red}"$@"${sgr}  # all lines red
fi
```

Comment: Read `man tput control_codes`.

Comment: I need some kind of loop that does the printf warn times and the rest as `printf` without `${red}` and `${sgr}`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean as your code doesn't actually print each argument on a separate line, but `while ((warn-- && $#)); do print-red-line; shift; done` would give you at most _warn_ red lines. Then `while (($#)); do print-normal-line; shift; done` would do the rest.

Comment: It does print each argument on a separate line because I use `'%s\n'` which gets repeated for each argument.

Comment: No need for negative `$warn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take advantage of existing tools that already know how to perform different actions based on various criteria (including the input line number).  e.g. awk, sed, perl, python, etc.

BTW, you can do this in sh, but why would you?  A shell loop is almost always the absolute worst way to do any form of text processing.

e.g.  The following uses shell to set the environment variables, and then `awk` to do the colour highlighting (in order to avoid a) counting the lines in shell and b) using a shell while read loop to do something slowly and clumsily that's fast and easy in `awk`)

```
colourise() {
  # colourise all (default) or the first N lines of stdin
  # where N is the optional first argument to the function.

  # check if arg is empty or numeric
  [ -z "$1" ] || [[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] \
    || echo "optional arg must be numeric if supplied" && exit 1

  local colour="$(tput setaf 9)"
  local sgr0="$(tput sgr0)"
  awk -v c="$colour" -v s="$sgr0" -v w="$1" \
    '(NR <= w || w == "") {print c $0 s; next}1'
}
```

BTW, you can hard-code the colour code and sgr code directly in the awk script...then you only have to pass the "$1" value to awk (alternatively, `export warn="$1"` in shell and use ENVIRON["warn"] in awk).  Note, though, that awk doesn't have a `tput` function, so you'd have to do that manually.  e.g. the following will work on most terminals that are similar to vt100 or ansi or xterm.

```
colourise() {
  local warn="$1"
  export warn

  awk 'BEGIN {c="\033[91m"; s="\033[m\017"; w=ENVIRON["warn"]}
       (NR <= w || w == "") {print c $0 s; next}1'
}
```

or (since it's not good to hard-code escape sequences for terminals):

```
colourise() {
  local warn="$1"
  local colour="$(tput setaf 9)"
  local sgr0="$(tput sgr0)"
  export warn colour sgr0

  awk 'BEGIN {c=ENVIRON["colour"]; s=ENVIRON["sgr0"]; w=ENVIRON["warn"]}
       (NR <= w || w == "") {print c $0 s; next}1'
}
```

Then just pipe whatever you like into the `colourise` function.  e.g.

```bsh
# colourise first three lines of an array
printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | colourise 3

# colourise all lines of head
head filename | colourise

# colourise only the first line of the output from several
# commands.   use a compound command {} or a sub-shell ()
# this does not colourise the first line of each command separately,
# only the first line of the combined output.
{
command1
command2
command3
} | colourise 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have resolved problem as follows

```
  if [[ -v f ]] && (( f != 0 )); then

    # print normal multi-line text
    [[ ! -v warn ]] && printf '%s\n' "$@"

    # print multi-line warnings
    
    if [[ -v warn && "$warn" =~ $rge ]]; then
        argc=$#
        argv=("$@")
        rge='^[0-9]+$'
        (( warn > argc )) && warn=$argc
    for (( j=0; j<argc; j++ )); do
          (( j+1 <= warn )) && printf '%s\n' ${red}"${argv[j]}"${sgr}
          (( j+1 > warn )) && printf '%s\n' "${argv[j]}"
    done
        #printf '%s\n' ${red}"$@"${sgr}  # all lines red
    fi

  fi
```